# Running Jenkins job with multiple browsers

Tags: jenkins, junit, nosetests

I am using the combination of Jenkins, python, unittest, nosetests to run test suites. I publish the results in nosetests.xml to Jenkins using Junit plugin.

My question: How can I run the same test suites with different browsers (Chrome, FF, IE,…,etc) and publish all the results in the same Jenkins job and still be able to distinguish each test result with respect to browser it used?

I am thinking about running the test suite many time, each with different browser and rename the tests in each nosetest report, nosetests.xml, before publishing to Jenkins but I don’t think that it is an elegant solution.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [multi-configuration jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) (or matrix jobs) are designed for in Jenkins.

You specify your job configuration once, but add one or more variables that should change each time, building a matrix of combinations (in your case, the matrix has one dimension: browser).

[image: Matrix definition]

Jenkins then runs one main build with multiple sub-builds — one for each combination in the matrix.  You can then clearly see the results for each combination.

[image: Matrix configurations and results]

This requires that your test job can be parameterised, i.e. you can choose at runtime which browser should be run, rather than running all tests together in a single job.

The Jenkins wiki has minimal documentation on this feature, but there are a few good [blog posts](http://blog.smartbear.com/test-automation/running-testcomplete-tests-with-multi-configuration-jenkins-projects/) (and Stack Overflow questions) out there on how to set it up.